# How to conform a class to a protocol in Swift and can protocol methods be overridden?

Tags: ios, swift, class, mocking, protocols

Is it necessary to use delegates to conform to a protocol? If yes, can anyone write an example code to show the same? Suppose I have a protocol ABC and I want to create a class for mocking the methods of ABC, how can this be done? I don't have very clear concepts of protocols and delegates. Please explain that too.

Comment: Search for tutorials and examples, I am sure you will find many like this : https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef.

Comment: "Is it necessary to use delegates to conform to a protocol?" You could use a class to define the delegate interface instead, but then that restricts all delegates to subclassing your superclass (rather than whatever superclass makes sense for them), so don't do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At first, protocol methods is unnecessary to conform, use **@objc optional** to define function:

---

`@objc optional func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)`

---

if no **@objc optional** that those methods must implement in delegates.

Answer (score 1):

Delegates are a design pattern that allows one object to send messages to another object when a specific event happens.

> ObjectA does not need to know the exact type of object B. It is
>   sufficient for Object A to know just know that object B conforms to
>   the FooDelegateProtocol
>
> Comment from Alexander.

Imagine an object A calls an object B to perform an action. Once the action is complete, object A should know that B has completed the task and take necessary action, this can be achieved with the help of delegates!

Mark Moykens explains delegation really good.

[Mark Moykens Delegation](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjprZblnsXXAhXCIVAKHYNXCT4QtwIILTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DRNtkg0az_Os&usg=AOvVaw0hV1ODraZ11MHIxrzvvK5D)

For Protocols you can look in the swift documentation, there are plenty of good examples.

[Swift Docs Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

For your ABC example:

```
protocol ABC {
  func exampleFunctionA()
  func examplefunctionB()
}



class ExampleClass: ABC {
  func exampleFunctionA() {
    // your code here
  }

  func examplefunctionB() {
    // your code here
  }


}
```

Comment: "one object to send messages to another object when a specific event happens" importantly: "without needing to know the exact type of object B. It is sufficient for Object A to know just know that object B conforms to the FooDelegateProtocol "

Comment: Thanks for your input I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an idea of protocols.

**Protocol**, in general, is a rule that everyone has to follow. When you implement some protocol, example you wrote protocol and put some methods in that protocol as optional and few methods as required. Once protocol implemented whatever that wants to follow the protocol that has to conform that protocol. Once conformed means, they are following it and they have to implmented all the required methods in that.

Now coming to **delegates**. Delegate helps in following a protocol. You will write a delegate that includes that protocol. When you assign self to delegate you are indirectly saying that this instance is following that protcol and those methods are here. So you will get a call backs to those methods.

Above explanation is given for you to just understand the concept. The more you want to look at it please refer to any article/blog available on net.